# log4net issue - Orchard on IIS8 Windows Server 2012

Tags: azure, log4net, orchardcms, iis-8, windows-server-2012

I'm deploying Orchard CMS onto an Azure VM (Windows Server 2012) with IIS8

I'm getting this error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

How can I fix this? :(

**UPDATE**

I tried a fresh copy of Orchard 1.7 and I get this issue :/

Answer (score 0):

1) Check that you have the "lib" folder deployed that contains all of orchards extra resources. It should have a series of resources such as autofac, Castle Windor etc, as well as log4net. If you can't find this folder at the route of your copy of 1.7 then that is probably the issue.

2) Orchard does not use nuget packages, but instead uses this lib folder (I believe that they have custom versions of several of the packages). If you got the source code version of 1.7, then this lib should have been present when you built. Check in VS to ensure that the references to log4net are point to a location that exists.